# VK_Api | vk_api.exceptions.AuthError: Unknown API auth error

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, auth

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


def captcha_handler(captcha):
    """ При возникновении капчи вызывается эта функция и ей передается объект
        капчи. Через метод get_url можно получить ссылку на изображение.
        Через метод try_again можно попытаться отправить запрос с кодом капчи
    """

    key = input("Enter captcha code {0}: ".format(captcha.get_url())).strip()

    # Пробуем снова отправить запрос с капчей
    return captcha.try_again(key)

def auth_handler():
    """ При двухфакторной аутентификации вызывается эта функция.
    """

    # Код двухфакторной аутентификации
    key = input("Enter authentication code: ")
    # Если: True - сохранить, False - не сохранять.
    remember_device = True

    return key, remember_device

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(
    '+Номер телефона', 'Пароль',
    # функция для обработки двухфакторной аутентификации
    auth_handler=auth_handler,
    captcha_handler=captcha_handler,  # функция для обработки капчи
    app_id=6123185
    )
    

vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()
```